# JButton Prints Multiple Times Instead of Once. Why?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton, actionlistener

I have a JButton and the code is below. When pressed it prints 3 times to the console instead of once. Why is it doing that and how to fix that? Thanks in advance! I also posted on code ranch.

```
    change61 = new JButton("N");
    change61.setLocation(0,0);
    change61.setSize(25,14);
    change61.setFocusPainted(false);
    change61.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    change61.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));
    change61.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 7));
    change61.setRolloverEnabled(false); // TEST
    change61.addActionListener(this);
    change61.setActionCommand("Normal");
    buttons16.add(change61);   

    change61.getModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                ButtonModel model = change61.getModel();
                if (model.isArmed()) {
                    cl1.setIcon(CL2);
                    lvrvr1.setIcon(LVRL);
                    dsw1.setIcon(LSIG);
                    dsy1.setIcon(CL1);
                    b1b.setIcon(LHC);
                    System.out.println("Button Pressed"); // THIS GETS PRINTED 3 TIMES TO CONSOLE INSTEAD OF ONCE

                } else {
                    cl1.setIcon(CL1);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within stateChagned method, use isPressed instead of isArmed. It should work.

Or as @camickr suggested

```
change61.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    cl1.setIcon(CL2);
                    lvrvr1.setIcon(LVRL);
                    dsw1.setIcon(LSIG);
                    dsy1.setIcon(CL1);
                    b1b.setIcon(LHC);
                    System.out.println("Button Pressed"); // THIS GETS PRINTED 3 TIMES TO CONSOLE INSTEAD OF ONCE
            }
        });
```

Comment: You should be using an ActionListener for a button click.

Comment: I was able to fix the multiple printing by putting the print statement in the } else { statement

Comment: cl1.setIcon(CL2); is used to simulate and led turning on and off with the press of a button

Answer (score 0):

Since the question got me hooked, I wanted to know why it is fired three times.

As the stacktrace reveals, the changes are fired by the mouse event.

First, the mouse is pressed. It calls DefaultButtonModel.isArmed(true) and DefaultButtonModel.isPressed(true). Each method triggers a change event. Here we have the first and second iteration.
Second, the mouse is released. It calls DefaultButtonModel.isPressed(false), again triggering a change event. The third iteration.

FYI, the DefaultButtonModel is the implementation of the ButtonModel- Interface.